# What the use of Website Push ID and how it differs from the normal APNS?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Hello everyone I have been doing push notifications the usual way. There also I can send push notification via a website via proper scripts. I am reading Website Push ID that you can send push messages directly from your website to os x. Any idea how does it differ? The OS X means iphone/ipad devices and mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented under the OS X Documentation (there's even an implementation video). You must be a developer to access the documentation since it is under NDA.

Apple publicly lists the documentation (but doesn't give access to) here: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

If only there were a search engine to see if people have disclosed information about "website push notifications available in OS X Mavericks" ...

Comment: @IanCarroll You get access to all documentation if you are a member of either development program.  Many OSX Articles address shared Cocoa Frameworks and some iOS Articles reference OSX specifics as well.  Apple gives all devs access to all articles, including Safari developer program articles.

Answer (score 1):

Without breaking any NDA agreements, I could liken it to receiving an email, but instead of the internet handling the delivery of the email, APNS is used (so apple have complete control over the flow of messages), and therefore it's got a distinct client target (not like email where you can use any email client).

this ultimately allows for very tight and deep integration.

Think email notifications on steriods!